# Aggregate numbers into classes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Assume the following table:

```
id    value
-----------
1      3
2      5
3      15
4      18
5      19
6      30
```

I am looking to categorize and count in a few groups:

```
group    amount
---------------
'1-5'      2
'6-10'     0
'11-20'    3
'21-50'    1
```

How can I do this in one query?

Comment: How can group '1-5' have amount of 2? Shouldn't it be 3+5+15+18+19 ?

Comment: id = 1 (value of 3) and Id = 2 value of 5) .. sorry, i want to COUNT not SUM the values.. will edit! So "group 1-5" means "this category holds the number of values that are either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to write the groups into a case when:

```
SELECT grp, count(*)
FROM
(
 SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN value BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5'
    WHEN value BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
    ...and so on...
    ELSE '21-50' 
  END as grp
 FROM
  sourcetable
)a
GROUP BY grp
```

Essentially you're converting values from one form to another, based on the range they fall into, then counting the converted values. Note, i've used an ELSE on the 21-50 range, assuming value never rises above 50. If it does, youre going to need to alter the ranges otherwise, technically, 100 will be filed under "21-50" also

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use a generated table of your ranges:

```
;WITH CTE_Groups AS (
    SELECT 1 AS min, 5 AS max, '1-5' AS grp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS min, 10 AS max, '6-10' AS grp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS min, 20 AS max, '11-20' AS grp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 21 AS min, 50 AS max, '21-50' AS grp
)
SELECT
    G.grp,
    COUNT(T.id) AS amount
FROM
    CTE_Groups G
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T ON T.value BETWEEN G.min AND G.max
GROUP BY
    G.grp, G.min
ORDER BY
    G.min
```